# How do I load a nested resource using cancan when the name of the nested model differs from the controller name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

given that I have a Worker model which is nested under Farm model, how do I correctly load the Worker resource in the Workers controller (called FarmWorkersController)? I've tried this...

```
class FarmWorkersController < ApplicationController
  load_resource :farm, :parent => true
  load_resource :class => 'Worker', :through => :farm, :parent => false

  # Note that :parent and :class need to be specified on the Worker resource line,
  # as the name of the controller (FarmWorkersController) is different from Worker model name
end
```

... but I get the error

```
undefined method `farm_workers' for #<Farm:0xa87670c>
```

Note that if I define a farm_workers() getter in the Farm model which returns the collection of Workers, then I don't get the error - though the Workers collection is not loaded for the index action. In any case, I don't want to pollute my model to make the controller authentication work.

(It shouldn't matter but I am using mongoid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but according to the docs/code, you should be able to specify the name as the first argument to `load_resource`:

```
load_resource :worker, :class => 'Worker', :through => :farm, :parent => false
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I tried your answer (with load_resource :worker instead of load_resource 'workers'). And it seems to have worked! I basically had omitted that first argument. Thanks!